# How do you get user input when running a fish script from a url?

Tags: shell, curl, command-line, fish

Consider this fish script :

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
while true
  read -l -P "Give me an answer [y/n]:" reply

  switch $reply
    case Y y
      return 0
    case '' N n
      return 1
  end
end
```

When run from the command line using :

```
$ ./script-name.fish
```

It works just as expected with the script waiting for you to answer y or n.

However when I upload to a url and attempt to run it using :

```
$ curl http://path.to/script-name.sh | fish
```

It gets stuck in a permanent loop, how do I run this script from a url and allow for user input?

Comment: You make the script support non-interactive use.

Comment: I did but that limits its value

Comment: Personally, l think enhancing a program to support both interactive and non-interactive uses _increases_ the utility. But if you insist on forcing interactive mode, then you can read directly from `/dev/console` (or equivalent) -- stdin is connected to the pipe, so you have to read directly from the input source.

Comment: The answer would be pretty much the same as it is for bash, zsh, ksh, etc. Read from */dev/tty*. Unfortunately, the fish job control is a bit broken so that won't work.